# Download all files from multiple Android apps

Tags: android

For various reasons that are too complicated to explain, I need to download all the files which would be found on an Android device which had the top 100 Google Play apps installed.

I have been told that Android Studio may be the way to go with this but does anyone else have any better solutions? Ideally I would like to keep the apps updated.

Comment: What do you mean by "all files"? Does this include system files? What about files that are created dynamically by using applications? No Android Studio will not do this, Android studio is for creating apps, not downloading them from the play store.

Comment: Hello Yes all system files but not dynamic files. Thanks,

Comment: Found this article and am trying out  BlueStacks. http://www.extremetech.com/computing/83812-run-android-apps-on-your-windows-pc-2/2 Will post the results here